# If $a+b$ and $ab$ are algebraic then $a,b$ are algebraic

Tags: extension-field

I need to show that if the sum and the product of two complex numbers is algebraic, then each of then is algebraic.

We have that the extensions $Q(a+b)/Q$ and $Q(ab)/Q$ are finite, so the extension $Q(a+b,ab)/Q$ is finite.

Since
$$[Q(a,b):Q]=[Q(a,b):Q(a+b,ab)] [Q(a+b,ab):Q],$$
it suffices to show that the extension $Q(a,b)/Q(a+b,ab)$ is finite, but I can't come up with an appropriate basis. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the roots of $X^2 - (a+b)X+ab = 0$?

Comment: The roots are $-(a+b) \pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. These are in Q(a+b,ab), but I'm afraid I don't see what your point is

Comment: No, the roots of this polynomial are exacly $a$ and $b$

Comment: Well, now that you changed it they are :P but thanks!